# Closing activities in android application

Tags: android

I m developing an android application.When I wish to close it,I need to close all the activities sequentially that I have opened earlier.Is there any code which closes the previously opened activity automatically when a new one is opened ?? And where it needs to be written ??

Comment: maybe you look for Activity lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html There are some kinds of ways in which you can manage your activities.

Comment: Yeahh.. I did read thru the stuff there... But didnt get a proper soln.. Thanks nywyz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use finish() method before or after you intent to another activity.Like this

```
Intent toAnotherActivity = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(toAnotherActivity);

finish();
```

Comment: Tried it too n it helped.. Thankyou :)

Comment: Nice to hear that. You can vote up may answer if it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, just add android:noHistory="true" attribute for all your activities. for example

```
<activity 
android:name=".ExampleActivity" 
android:noHistory="true" />
```

Quote from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

> android:noHistoryWhether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". 
>   A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

This attribute was introduced in API Level 3.

Comment: I did try that attribute and its woking properly.. Thankyou :)

Comment: Glad to hear i could help you